# Missing OData envelope/context

Tags: .net-core, odata

When I request some data through OData I will get the data as requested, but not the OData envelope/context. This means that any OData functionality wont work for the client.

I am trying to understand the reason why I do not get the OData envelope together with the data.

The setup is as follows:

- .Net Core
- OData
- PostgreSQL

I am requesting data with this url: http://localhost:5000/odata/mycontroller/mydbview.

The controller class:

```
public class MyController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("MyController/MyDBView")]
    public IActionResult GetSeasonView(int id)
    {
        var requestedItems = myTableContext.MyDBView;

        return Ok(requestedItems);
    }
}
```

The EDM model:

```
public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var odataModelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    odataModelBuilder.EntitySet<MyDataDto>("My");

    return odataModelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

The data object looks like:

```
[Table("datatable", Schema = "api")]
public class MyDataDto
{
    [Key] 
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public uint Total { get; set; }
  
    <Continues with more data>
```

The view, which is a subset of the data table, looks like:

```
[Table("datatable", Schema = "api")]
public class MyDBView
{
    [Key]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public uint total { get; set; }
}
```

Any sugestions to what could be wrong with this setup? I have tried to follow this guide btw: https://www.laboremus.ug/post/using-sql-views-with-entity-framework-code-first

## Update

I have found the problem but still not a solution. The problem is that the entity set is registered as a MyDataDTO while the return value is a MyDBView.

I still don't know the solution though.

Comment: Do you want to access this as a GET or POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues, your intended route does not conform to OData which makes it hard to interpret your expected usage, is this a collection, or item based request? For instance you have an 'id' parameter that is not used within the method, and the route prefix `MyController` doesn't match the controller registration through the route `My`.

For this solution I can demonstrate the configuration for both scenarios:

- A Collection bound function to return the entire view
- An Item bound function to return the view scoped to a given item Id

You need to *register* the *View DTO* with the OData model if you want to use the `IActionResult` as the response type on your endpoint method, alternatively can return `IQueryable<MyDbView>`.

- this can work because now the attribute routes can identify the intended type to return
- but `IActionResult` gives you the flexibility to return error responses or other standard forms of the response.

Lets look at the 2 methods for this view, one returns the entire view and will support `$filter` query options, the other returns a record from the view for an individual item:

***NOTE:** I have changed the names of the methods from your example to reduce confusion with the configuration*

```
public class MyController : ODataController
{
    // example route: ~/My/DBView
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DBView()
    {
        var requestedItems = myTableContext.MyDBView;
        return Ok(requestedItems);
    }

    // example route: ~/My(id)/asDBView
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AsDBView(int key)
    {
        var requestedItem = myTableContext.MyDBView.Where(x => x.Id == key);
        return Ok(requestedItems);
    }
}
```

Now we care register these routes with the OData model through the `IEdmBuilder`. For the view to support querying, you will need to specify conceptual name of the dataset, but this doesn't need to correspond to an actual controller.

```
public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var odataModelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    // Initialize your OData EntitySets
    odataModelBuilder.EntitySet<MyDataDto>("My");

    // initialize the Custom DTOs
    odataModelBuilder.EntitySet<MyDbView>("MyDbViewFakeSet"); 
    // NOTE: Name is arbitrary, but MUST be unique across all EntitySets.

    // Register the Function endpoints on your "My" controller
    odataModelBuilder.EntitySet<MyDataDto>("My")
                     .Collection.Function("DBView")
                     .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<MyDbView>("MyDbViewFakeSet");

    odataModelBuilder.EntitySet<MyDataDto>("My")
                     .EntityType.Function("asDBView")
                     .ReturnsFromEntitySet<MyDbView>("MyDbViewFakeSet");


    return odataModelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```